# UITableViewController cell fadeout

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell, fadeout

I'm creating a UINavigationController based app. And in the first view i have a UITableViewController.

I want to have the same behaviour that the Contacts App have.
1) User select contact
2) System show contact details 
3) User selects que back button
4) System returns to the tableview, and fadeout the cell

I can only do this if i create a UIViewController, and a xib with a UITableView.
And then add the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if ([self.mytableView indexPathForSelectedRow] != nil){
        [self.mytableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.mytableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I really don't want to have a xib only for this. So is it possible to do it in with a UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A `UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` so you can overide the `viewDidAppear:animated` method however you wish.

If you want to create the `UITableViewControl` programmatically (i.e. without loading it from a nib), you'll have to manually configure the `UITableView`.  See the following in the [`UITableViewController` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> - If a nib file is specified via the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method (which is declared by the superclass `UIViewController`),  `UITableViewController` loads the table view archived in the nib file.  Otherwise, it creates an unconfigured `UITableView` object with the correct  dimensions and autoresize mask. You can access this view through the `tableView` property.
> - If a nib file containing the table view is loaded, the data source and delegate become those objects defined in the nib file (if any). If no nib file is specified or if the nib file defines no data source or delegate, `UITableViewController` sets the data source and the delegate of the table view to `self`.

Comment: Yes, i know, but when i override the viewDidAppear:animated to deselect the row it won't work, because the UITableViewController already deselects the row, but don't show the row to the user.

Sorry for the poor english...

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` to make the selected row visible before deselecting it.  You could try doing that either above the call to `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` in `viewDidAppear`or perhaps earlier in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Ok i found the problem.
In the viewWillAppear i have the [self.tableView reloadData] because i may change the content of the my data.
And if i test the [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] before the reloadData, i get nil so that didn't work.
If i don't call the reloadData method, the cell fadeout correctly, but my data may not be up to date, so is there other way to achieve this?